# div filling up all remaining white space (not 3 columns)

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs stacked on top of one another:

- div1 20px
- div2 take up remaining screen height
- div3 20px

How can I have div2 take up remaining screen height?

note: i don't want to use javascript.

Comment: have you tried giving the middle div width:100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>

#top,#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#top { top:0; }
#bottom { bottom:0; }
#middle {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: this work great! thx! the top/bottom: 0px for #middle was what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to check my answer to indicate your problem is solved =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
<div id="top">
    top div
</div>
<div id="middle">
    middle div
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    bottom div
</div>

#top {
    height: 20px;
}

#bottom {
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See this code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/PzA3W/